# Multiple Databases, fewer tables? One database, many tables?

Tags: database-design

I recently got a job working in IT, and while my specialty is application design, I've been tasked with fixing, and renovating their current database structure and applications.

Their current database contains 20 interconnected databases, with hundreds upon hundreds of different views (no stored procedures). Everything is tied to a series of access front ends.

Now the server architecture is very odd, there are a ton of duplicate tables across databases containing identical or nearly identical data, so obviously much of this can be merged down. However, the way the previous developer laid out the applications was to have a separate database for every single application, with another database called "Shared_Tables" that contains ***SOME*** of the information that needs to be passed between tables.

Now my main question is, since I'm basically starting from scratch on creating a new system structure for the company, is there any real advantage to using separated databases, or would merging them all into 1 database be just as efficient, assuming they're running all on the same instance?

Also, worth noting, none of the databases have primary keys, unique keys, foreign keys, etc. And the datatypes across many fields differ when they should be the same.

Comment: **First** fix the *no primary key, foreign keys* issues - once that's in place, and working - *then* think about anything else .... whoever "designed" such a database should be banned from ever touching a keyboard again ....

Comment: There's close to 5 years worth of data contained within the database, in some cases I've tried to start creaking primary keys and foreign keys, but it has lead to some other issues cropping up. When I say this database is a nightmare, it's a vast understatement.

And fixing the PK/FK issue is another major problem as many of the PK/FK span across multiple databases...

Comment: Once the system is somewhat stable and has proper PK+FK, I would try to see just how many tables could be eliminated by merging those databases. I tend to argue that fewer databases are better in general - don't split up your tables into too many databases. You cannot do declarative referential integrity across database boundaries, for instance. If you have too many tables - try to use SQL Server's **schema** feature - great for handling permissions, too, based on "areas" of functionality.

Comment: And btw - I feel for you - been there, tried done - gave up in the end :-( (in my case, it was 10+ years of "designing" by some utter morons .... several of them, too, with varying styles of screwing up....)

Comment: @marc_s - once the pk, fk are in place can we simply do this - Do "table difference" and store diffs in an audit table, and merge the data of two tables ?

Comment: That's the great part, each database has its own custom schema, so the organizational part is practically done, but there is absolutely 0 referential integrity, and permissions are all over the place. Also, the company doesn't use domain users, rather locally managed work stations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @dean's post. Also the posts which recommend starting to hack straight away the database structures is a bad idea. If the databases are that many and with the amount of tables you mention then you will cause more problems than solve them (performance and regression bugs being a big one).

I recommend the following:

1. Do your analysis on the current state of the company's databases (looks like you have done this already). Pin point exactly where the problems are and relay this to your managers in jargon they understand. That is, these are the list of problems, it will take this many man years to fix the current system etc.
2. Ascertain what the current and future requirements are. Where is this company going with their IT systems and what are their data requirements are in each case. Then work out whether the current structure can handle/support their current/future requirements. If not, again pin point with supporting evidence why this can't be done. Again relay to managers in a jargon they can understand.

What is the point of (1) and (2) above? The point is that it is extremely difficult to come on a project as you have with no background in the history of that IT systems and start hacking away with confidence, especially the merging of the tables as you mention. You need to convince your managers that the best bet is to start fresh, and for that you need concrete evidence to back up your suggestion (i'm assuming you would rather design from scratch than hack the current database structures).

It would be much better to start from a blank piece of paper and design the system you see fit based on the current and future requirements. You will still need to analyse the existing structure but you take only what you need for the new database design. Good luck and I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you're approaching the problem from the wrong end.

If you have a luxury to redesign from scratch, start with logical data design. Think of a database as a unit of correctness (all the constraints are database contained and all the constraints should be true). Ientify your entities and relationships between them. Identify keys. Dedup and normalize. Only after that you should concern yourself with performance and efficiency. Not saying that you won't end up changing some of that beautiful design for better performance, just that one should always start with solid data model.

The answer to "how many databases" question will follow naturally from there.